# Is there a way to trigger a jvm thread dump on an Oracle exception?

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, deadlock

We've got a Java program that runs in Websphere, and uses an Oracle database using straight jdbc (no Hibernate or JPA).  Our customer is doing load testing using HP Performance Center, and he's getting occasional Oracle "deadlock" exceptions under load

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

Is there a way to, either in the code or externally, force the same sort of thread dump you get when you `kill -3` the jvm when this exception happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Knowing how to enumerate threads won't be of much use if you can't detect automatically *when* the exception happens.

We do this all the time.  We're basically using:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
```

when our app starts up and then we dump the infos we want when an exception occurs:

- `Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> mst = Thread.getAllStackTraces();`
- `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`/ `maxMemory()` / `totalMemory()` to get basic memory infos
- user usage pattern if it's an app the user can interact with
- house-made "analytics"
- etc.

You can then call a lot of other things and get fancy.  For example we're automatically sending crash reports (including the full stack trace) to a server waiting for such traces.

Comment: +1; I remember when I discovered that tidbit, little lightbulbs happened.

Comment: `kill -3` has, as well as the stack trace of each thread, information on what locks each thread has acquired and is waiting on.  Does `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` have that as well?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: I don't think so.  We're using the *findDeadlockedThreads* method to find the deadlocks (on a JVM that supports this call).

Answer (score 1):

For the current thread, you can use [Thread.dumpStack()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack%28%29).

For all threads, you can either use [Thread.enumerate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#enumerate%28java.lang.Thread%5B%5D%29) to get all running threads and dumpStack() each of them or you can use [Thread.getAllStackTraces()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces%28%29) and print those out to the console or wherever you need to.

To get this to happen when these exceptions occur, if you can't do this in your own code, you could try AOP, writing an agent (if you are using Java 6+) or you could, in a pinch, grab the source code of SQLException, change it to dump the stack in its constructor, recompile and put this class back in the boot class path before everything else.